# pandas efficient row selection along df/time index

Tags: pandas

I've built a pd.DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
index  time                 value

1      1999/01/01, 00:10    18
2      1999/01/01, 00:15    79 
3      1999/01/01, 00:25    21
...
100    1999/01/01, 03:55    27
...
```

The rows number in the millions, span multiple years, and are ordered by UTC time (`time[i] >= time[j]` for all `i>j`). I'm looking to build an index so that i can iterate effectively over a *subset* of the data.

How can I efficiently index rows with `time` values close to 00:00z, 06:00z, 12:00z or 18:00z (say, +/-15 mins from each time point). For example, `index[0]` would produce all rows with timestamps close to 00z (11:45 ... 00:15) on Jan 1, 1999, `index[5]` would correspond to data at or near 06:00, on Jan 2, 1999, etc.

Just to clarify, I'm looking to compute and cache the `index`, then use it repeatedly to look up things into my large dataframe.

Minimal code example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)

rows = 50000
data = np.random.rand(rows)
# 1-minute frequency here, but real data are irregularly spaced
tidx = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=rows, freq='T')
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({"time": tidx, "value": data})
data_frame.head(10)
```

In this case, `index[0]` would return

```
                   time     value
0   2010-01-01 00:00:00  0.417022
1   2010-01-01 00:01:00  0.720324
2   2010-01-01 00:02:00  0.000114
....
15  2010-01-01 00:15:00  0.670468
```

whereas `index[1]` would return all (31) entries recorded on Jan 1, 2010 between `05:45 ... 06:15`, etc. If a certain index has no valid data points, then it should be set to `None` (or an empty dataframe, whatever's most convenient).

Comment: Could you make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341)? It looks like you could generate example data using [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and random seeded values, and for the sake of example you only need two day's worth of data.

Comment: Perhaps if you use a function for [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)'s `by` parameter, the index you want could be created.

Comment: I think I found a solution, but I'm shaky on the details, so I'm waiting for an example.

Comment: @wjandrea added an example :) thanks!

Comment: OK, I tried writing an answer, but it ended up being too broad (like 4 separate topics) so I realized, what specifically do you need help with? Like, what have you tried, and how did you get stuck? And on the flip side, what are you going to use it for? [Iteration in Pandas is an anti-pattern](/a/55557758), so maybe it'd be better to do something like `groupby().apply()`? That wouldn't actually change the code in my solution very much, but conceptually it's different. Beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Check out [ask] for more tips, like how to write a good title.

Comment: I found this question during my research, if it helps: [Filtering out specific hours each day in pandas](/q/66285722/4518341)